# An array of length N can contain values 1,2,3 ... N^2. Is it possible to sort in O(n) time?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, radix-sort

Given an array of length N. It can contain values from ranging from 1 to N^2 (N squared) both inclusive, values are integral. Is it possible to sort this array in O(N) time? If possible how?

Edit: This is not a homework.

Comment: Your values are intergral, I assume? You can do it with integers

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Yes integral, I added that info in the question, thanks.

Comment: @danben: I've been told that meta-tags such as homework are deprecated.  Of course I can't find the reference now.  Perhaps a moderator/superuser could comment..?

Comment: @Bob Jarvis - here is a link to Jeff Atwood's take on the issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/is-homework-an-exception/60495#60495

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Write each integer in base N, that is each x can be represented as (x1, x2) with x = 1 + x1 + x2*N. Now you can sort it twice with [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), once on x1 and once on x2, resulting in the sorted array.

**EDIT:** As others mentioned below, sorting on each 'digit' separately like this is is called a [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort). Sorting on each digit with counting sort takes O(N) time and O(N) space (in this particular case). Since we repeat it exactly twice, this gives a total running time of O(N).

Comment: A two phase bucket sort. You first count how many entries a bucket will have, and from that the start index of each bucket(takes O(n)). Then you can inplace swap the entries into each bucket in O(n) too.

Comment: I think the rest of the world calls this a radix sort.

Comment: -1 because I think this answer is significantly less clear than @svick's answer.

Comment: I've only heard the term "counting sort" used to describe a procedure in which duplicated keys will cause duplicated records to be output.  The term "bucket sort" would normally be used to describe a single-pass stable partitioning operation, and "radix sort" to describe multi-pass partitioning.

Comment: @supercat: See [Counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). Bucket sort is an alternative algorithm that has the same complexity as Counting sort. Radix sort is a sorting algorithm that sorts arbitrary lists of integers by applying [counting sort or bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Definition) repeatedly to sort each digit separately. Note that it's crucial for Radix sort to work that both Counting sort and Bucket sort are stable. So basically I don't understand how your comment is relevant.

Comment: Counting sort on base 10 needs you to go from 0 -> 9, and find all elements in that order, so it will be O(10 * N) = O(n). If you are using base n, you'll need to look for all values in each digit from 0 -> n - 1, so counting sort will need O(n * n) = O(n^2), no?

Comment: @ybungalobill i am not able to understand `x = 1 + x1 + x2*N. ` . If we represent number in base `N` , N^2 can be expressed in maximum  2 bits , x1 and x2 then `x = x1 * n^0 + x2 * n^1 ` = `x1 + x2 * N` . please clarify .

Comment: @anon: `N^2` is *three* digits in base `N`, namely `100`. The numbers `0, ..., N^2-1` inclusive are all the two-digit numbers. Hence you need to add one to get `1, ..., N^2` as in the OP.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can, using [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Least_significant_digit_radix_sorts) with *N* buckets and two passes. Basically, you treat the numbers as having 2 digits in base *N*.

Comment: i am not able to understand `x = 1 + x1 + x2*N` as told in accepted answer  . If we represent number in base `N` , `N^2` can be expressed in maximum 2 bits , x1 and x2 then `x = x1 * n^0 + x2 * n^1` = `x1 + x2 * N` . please clarify .

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to sort any array of integers with a well defined maximum value in `O(n)` time using a [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).  This is likely the case for any list of integers you encounter.  For example if you were sorting a list of arbitrary precision integers it wouldn't be true.  But all the C integral types have well-defined fixed ranges.