# How to sort n^2 elements in 2n RAM

Tags: algorithm

Can somebody please tell me how to sort n^2 elements using 2n amount of RAM.
One possible approach is to divide into n arrays of size n each. And then do a merge sort within the n elements and then finally keep a size n heap on the n arrays. However, this would mean that every time one element gets placed, I do a disk read, and every time n elements complete, I do a disk write. 
Any better suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Another way to phrase the question is "How to sort n elements in O(log(n)) RAM".

Comment: Shouldn't that be O(sqrt(n))?

Comment: Knuth has a whole chapter on this problem in *The Art of Computer Programming* Volume 3.

Comment: I believe it's somehow connected to http://stackoverflow.com/q/4238460/395626

Comment: This question is different, I think he means 2n amout of RAM with the array on the disk. So you have to use 2n amout of ram each time and store the result on disk.

Comment: I'm agree with @Fabio F, and @user515974 edit your question to clarify if you have another space which is not `RAM`.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to have a cache-oblivious priority queue implementation lying around, you can use it to achieve an optimal running time in terms of memory transfers at each level in the disk and memory hierarchy (See http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.897/spring05/lec/lec23.pdf).

Otherwise, if you just want to write simple code from scratch, a disk-based implementation of mergesort should work well. Basically, you can sort a range of the array by first recursively sorting the "left" and "right" halves, and then merging them using the 2n memory to buffer the recursively sorted sub-arrays from disk. For a simple implementation, this is not in place, so you will have to keep two copies of the array on disk and shuttle back and forth.

Comment: Hang on, if you have n^2 elements, how are you going to do the final merge in 2n memory?

Comment: You are buffering the numbers from disk. You have two lists on disk that you want to merge, so you load n from each into memory and merge them, writing the results of the merge to disk. When one of the buffers runs out, you reload it. Technically, you should also be buffering when you write to disk, so you may need to set aside O(n) memory for the output buffer as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You need n^2 memory for the elements alone.

If you don't count this obvious memory consumption, I recommend one of the inplace sort algorithms, such as heapsort. It will take O(1) extra space.

If you are looking for an external sort algorithm where the external storage doesn't count but only the internal one, I recommend to use bottom-up mergesort. You can get this to consume as much or as little internal memory as you want to; to consume approximately 2n memory, always read n/2 elements from each partially-sorted set, and merge them into another array of n elements; then write the result back to disk (preferably into a separate file).

Comment: There is no need to load all data at first.

Comment: But you have to store them somewhere. Even on disk, they still take O(n^2) bytes of storage.

Comment: OP, says he has O(n) `RAM`, where he said he has no O(n^2) space? his suggestion for solving problem say exactly he has external space.